# Difference between Warriors and Zelda control style

Tags: hyrule-warriors

Upon first starting the game, I am asked to pick between Warriors and Zelda control style.  What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Zelda Style

Y - Combo Attacks
X - Special Attack
B - Regular Attacks
A - Dodge

### Warriors Style

Y - Regular Attacks
X - Combo Attacks
B - Dodge
A - Special Attack

In Zelda Style, you generally keep your right thumb on the lower-left side of the buttons. In Warriors Style, you generally keep your right thumb on the upper left side of the buttons.

**Source:** The Controller Settings: Button Settings menu.