# What do the different control styles mean?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-legends

The game is asking me to pick a control style. My choices are "Warriors" or "Zelda" and while they tell me I can change this at any time from the settings menu, they don't actually say what the difference is.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185298/difference-between-warriors-and-zelda-control-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the control scheme of the face buttons.

For Warriors, Y is the normal attack and X is the special attack. For Zelda, B is the normal attack and A is the special attack. That's the only difference as far as I know.